# How to connect to my Synology NAS using OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, nas, ssl, ssl-certificate, synology

I have a Synology NAS at home. I have installed the VPN Server package and enabled Open VPN. I don't want to use the QuickConnect and I want to minimise the number of port for port forwarding. I understand that there will be at least one port I need to port forward (the OpenVPN server one) I have the following questions.

How do I access my photos on the Synology using the DS Photo app or Moments app from my iPhone? I have installed OpenVPN app on the iPhone along with DS Photo and Moments app.

Do I need to register my NAS with a Domain Name Provider? like buy a unique name on the internet if I want to connect using OpenVPN?

Do i need to buy a new digital certificate for my NAS? Or is it enough to use the default certificate that Synology provides with the NAS?

Will my NAS be exposed on the internet?

Finally, will the communication between my device and the NAS be secure?

Comment: Your question implies you are missing a number of important elements. First off, are you planning on accessing the NAS from outside your home LAN? If so you need to port forwarding port 1194 in your router to the NAS and sort out a way to reach your router externally, eg dynamic DNS or static IP.

Comment: I have set the NAS to have a static IP within the home network. How do I make my router reachable externally?

Comment: You set up port forwarding on  port 1194 udp (for OpenVPN) to the IP of the NAS in the router. You will still need a solution to find your routers external IP remotely (Dynamic DNS is one solution)

Answer (score 0):

Synology has a built in function for what you are trying to achieve.  I'm fairly sure you can do this without a VPN.  The only thing you need to setup on your NAS is the dynamic DNS which is free.

Goto control panel > External Access > DDNS tab > click add.

Use the synology service provider.  I can't remember all the setup details but there are lots of guides online for this.   Here is one i got by googling "How to setup Dynamic DNS on synology" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STlKmQE5luM

Once complete, you just put the host name you created in DS photo or any other DS app.  Use your sign on credentials and you're good to go.

Pretty sure you don't need QuickConnect for this to work too....but only 95% sure.